# Constructor is not called

Tags: c#, constructor

```
public class Unit
{
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public Engine EngineStuff { get; set; }

}
public class Engine
{
    public int PS { get; set; }
    public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
}

var unit = new Unit();
unit.UnitId = 3; //OK because Unit-constructor was called
unit.EngineStuff.PS = 200; //error, because EngineStuff-constructor obviously wasn't called.
```

How can this "inner" constructor be called?
I thought it initializes it automatically?

How can I simply assign a value to the property "EngineStuff.PS"?

Comment: It is not about constructors, you just don't allocate an object for the variable. They are never automatically allocated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to instantiate object's properties explicitly:

```
public class Unit
{
    public Unit()
    {
        EngineStuff = new Engine();
    }
}
```

---

Or if you want to manually control when to instantiate:

```
var unit = new Unit();
unit.UnitId = 3; 
unit.EngineStuff = new Engine();
unit.EngineStuff.PS = 200;
```

or simpler:

```
var unit = new Unit { UnitId = 3 };
unit.EngineStuff = new Engine { PS = 200 };
```

Comment: Or use the new syntax: `public Engine EngineStuff { get; set; } => new Engine()` or `public Engine EngineStuff  => new Engine();`

Answer (score 4):

Simply you need to initialize `EngineStuff` in either `Unit` constructor or just before using it.

```
public class Unit
{
    public Unit()
    {
        EngineStuff = new Engine();
    }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public Engine EngineStuff { get; set; }

}
```

Or :

```
var unit = new Unit();
unit.UnitId = 3;
unit.EngineStuff = new Engine():
unit.EngineStuff.PS = 200;
```

Answer (score 2):

`EngineStuff` is just a reference, you need to set its value to an `Engine` object that you create, either in the `Unit` constructor, a property initializer, or plain code.

So either:

```
// Constructor
public class Unit
{
    public Unit() { EngineStuff = new Engine(); }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public Engine EngineStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Or

```
// Property initializer
var unit = new Unit
{
    UnitId = 3,
    EngineStuff = new Engine { PS = 200 }
};
```

Or

```
// Plain code
var unit = new Unit();
unit.UnitId = 3;
unit.EngineStuff = new Engine { PS = 200 };
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to set it explicitly like below cause `EngineStuff` is of type `Engine` and so you will have instantiate it first before accessing any of it's member.

```
 unit.EngineStuff = new Engine { PS = 10, MaxSpeed = 2000 };
```

(OR) you can change your `Unit` class to have `EngineStuff` as a getter property and have the instance created there like below

```
    public Engine EngineStuff 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return new Engine();
        }
    }
```

Then you can access it

```
        var unit = new Unit();
        unit.UnitId = 3;
        unit.EngineStuff.PS = 100;
```

Comment: The second option won't really work since every time you return a new instance.

Comment: @abatishchev, I intentionally didn't included the null check. main intention was just show the alternative option keeping in mind that probably rest OP can figure out himself.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to other answers, you can define a getter property to create the instance when you need it first time:

```
public class Unit
{
    public int UnitId { get; set; }

    private Engine engineStuff;
    public Engine EngineStuff
    {
        get
        {
            if (engineStuff == null) engineStuff = new EngineStuff();
            return engineStuff;
        }
    }
}
```